# I want to test major changes on my website without hurting SEO

Tags: seo, domains, htaccess, redirects, downtime

I want to replace all my website files for new ones on the server and to test if they work alright but I don't want to be crawled while this is happening or if I am, 
I don't want the crawler to be able to see what's in the new page.

I just want to change it for like 15min but i tested other stuff once for 5min and google for webmasters told me they had a lot of 404's during that period and I don't want that to happen again.

Besides that I don't want to have to write my whole .htaccess file. I considered redirecting all the urls to my main page and apply the changes but I think this isn't probably a good practice, any good ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options:

1. Set up a local site for testing purposes. Something like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) should do the trick.
2. If you're going to do the testing on your live server, temporarily block your site while doing your testing. A [307 HTTP response would be appropriate](http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/20070704.htm).
3. Use [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to keep crawlers and everybody else out while you do your testing. Since your site will be "down" for only 15 minutes there will be no side effects from this.

Comment: i'm already using XAMPP and it's working great but for .htaccess changes and other stuff it behaves good sometimes but to test some of the changes it's just impossible using this kind of method. your other options are probably better on this particular case. thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't do testing in a production environment if at all possible. It's a recipe for disaster.
2. Create a testing subdomain that's isolated from your production site as much as possible. This will allow you to test you changes on the server without, hopefully, endangering your production site. You can use robots.txt to block 'bots from this subdomain so it won't be indexed.
3. Ideally, you want to have your own development system, a development server, a testing server, a staging server and then production. You can cut out two of the in-between servers if you must but going directly from a desktop web environment to production has resulted in some of the worst messes I've been involved in.

Comment: +1 Because it will likely not be just 15 minutes.  Buy a second domain name (your site name .biz or .info)

Comment: good suggestions but not very practical for me at the moment.

Comment: @MrChrister that's a good one, i have a list of domains i'm considering buying so that's a good option

Comment: @wxiiir - subdomains are a good way to go if you can't invest in multiple server environments right now. Unless you have really poor hosting they're quick and easy to create and free. Even using a subfolder is better than potentially wrecking your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit radical but I came up with a solution for my whole IT office a number of years ago.  We were looking for a better Operating System than windows.  We went through some phases, but ended up using Linux Mint with the Mate Desktop. The learning curve was very low. Because it is based on **Ubuntu** you can load a **Real LAMP Server**, complete with domain names, and fully working .htaccess (which we use on every project).  With Geany as a near match replacement for Notepad Plus Plus our IT Developer team appreciates each having a fully working apache2 server in their computer.

Of course this won't work if your shop is stuck with Windows, but for some people it is a perfect solution with low or no cost.